# File already exists error while writing Spark dataframe to S3 using AWS Glue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm using this command to write a dataframe to S3:

```
df.write.option("delimiter","|").option("header",True).option("compression", "gzip").mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("s3://bucketname/metrics/parsed/")
```

But I'm always getting this error, just the filename keeps changing:

```
An error occurred while calling o293.save. File already exists:s3://bucketname/metrics/parsed/part-01195-6ef08750-dbf5-41c6-b024-501403820268-c000.csv.gz
```

Full error:

```
"Failure Reason": "JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1195 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 1195.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 3023) (172.36.67.235 executor 9):
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: File already exists
```

I tried the following but it didn't work, and ends up giving the same error:

1. Added `coalesce(100)` in the command
2. Writing to a new destination, with and without the `.mode("overwrite")` option
3. Exporting the data in parquet format
4. Writing with `.mode("append")` option

I couldn't find anything helpful which could help resolve this, except [this post](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/spark-job-failed-after-reclaimed-spark-staging-xxx-file-already-exists-exception) but I'm using Glue 3.0 (Spark 3.1) hence this shouldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error displayed by Glue was not the correct exception. Although the task stages failed due to this error, but before this there was a stage failure due to an Exception in the code.

After setting up Spark UI on Glue, I was able to find the first failure and the cause of it.

[Here's](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/utilities/Spark_UI/README.md) how to setup Spark UI